# PHP 5.4 Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: php

Here is my code: `$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','the correct pass here');`

And what I get is: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`

This was working a day ago when I used it. Now, without changing a thing, it doesn't work anymore.

Why is the username blank? It should say root.

Any help would be appreciated. This whole setup has been working fine for months, and this particular script for a couple of weeks. I am not even sure how to debug this. What should I look for in PHP.ini.

The server is latest Debian, NGINX/PHP-FPM, PHP 5.4 Mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct password set? Do you have other mysql_connect laying around?

Comment: @AmalMurali Even if it will be removed, you can still user PDO to access mysql_ functions, this shouldn't affect existing code. But you are correct, for new code MySQLI/PDO should be used.

Comment: @AzizSaleh .. could you tranlsate that in english?

Comment: I think the root user might be a problem. You should create a user for the database and only use the database user. It's bad to have root or admin passwords in plain text.

Comment: @tereško Not sure what you mean. If you are asking how to access mysql_ functions using PDO, check this out: https://github.com/azizsaleh/mysql

Comment: I know it will be deprecated, which is why I am running 5.4 not 5.5

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this method it's very simple :

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_Password');
mysql_select_db("db_name");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: would be better if you dont use deprecated functions as Amal said. convert with mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_pass","my_db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is essentially what I already have. That's how I got the error :)